# how to use Sikuli Right Click

Tags: sikuli

My automation is working but this part of the script is not working where by I should right clcik on where the mouse is located. The page is silverlight and shortcut key like shift + f10 is not working. The best option is to use this. But this code is not working. I tried rightclick(atMouse)) is not working.... It does not even recognise rightclick()

```
s.mouseMove("C:\\tvmtrends\\images_tvm\\313.png");
rightclick();                     

  if(s.exists("C:\\tvmtrends\\images_tvm\\313.png") != null) {
   Thread.sleep(3000);
 s.click("C:\\tvmtrends\\images_tvm\\313.png");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out now :

```
s.mouseMove("C:\\tvmtrends\\images_tvm\\313.png");
                              Thread.sleep(1000);
                              s.mouseDown(Button.RIGHT);
                              Thread.sleep(1000);
                              s.mouseUp(Button.RIGHT);
                              Thread.sleep(1000);                    

  if(s.exists("C:\\tvmtrends\\images_tvm\\313.png") != null) {
   Thread.sleep(3000);
 s.click("C:\\tvmtrends\\images_tvm\\313.png");
```